# CheerioJS Select one out of of three div elements with the same class name

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

```
<div class="container"> ... </div>
<div class="container"> ... </div>
<div class="container"> ... </div>


var mp4src =$(".container").html() 
console.log(mp4src)
```

This code prints the html of the first div, how can I only print the third one?

Comment: @JustLearning does it work, my answer?

Comment: Yes it does thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [eq](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) to get the item of specific position

Here is the code:

```js
var mp4src = $(".container").eq(2).html();
console.log(mp4src)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"> 1... </div>
<div class="container"> 2... </div>
<div class="container"> 3... </div>
```